# How much abstraction do I need for my code to be properly testable?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm currently working on an language interpreter, more specifically on the data model of that language, my data model should be able to understand expression and interpret them eg: "cos(a + 4)" should be interpreted as the cosinus of the value in the variable a plus 4, I'll keep this example to explain my how it works.

I choose to break down expression interpretation into multiple steps :

1. Creating a list of tokens from the expression eg: `cos(a + 4)` become `[ "cos", "(", "a", "+", "4" ]`
2. Converting mathematical operators to functions eg: `[ "cos", "(", "a", "+", "4" ]` become `[ "cos", "(", "sum", "(", "a", ",", "4", ")" , ")" ]`
3. Creating a parsing tree from this list of tokens with the following rules : if open parenthesis you go down, if closed parenthesis you go up, if comma you go to the right else you write the current token to the current node eg: `[ "cos", "(", "sum", "(", "a", ",", "4", ")", ")" ]` becomes this tree :

```
    cos
      \
      sum
      / \
     a   4
```

4. Use a recursive function that interprets the tree

Everything works fine but I want my code to be well tested and I wonder how I should separate the classes of my program.

Right now I have this logic separated into 2 classes, a parser which does the first 3 steps and an interpreter which does the last one.

Should I break down my parser into a tokenizer, a operatorConverter, and a treeBuilder to have each functionality well separated and have each of those classes tested independently instead of having a parser class with 3 independents functions that I test as the parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the actual code and on your personal preference. Splitting the parser up into several stages or modules sure makes testing and mainting easier. How much modularization makes sense for you is not something that can be answered by anybody but you. If you choose the granule of your modules and it turns out to be too coarse-grained or to fine-grained, you can still split or join later.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently working on an language interpreter.

Then you should read books like [*the Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science)), Queinnec's [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lisp-in-small-pieces/66FD2BE3EDDDC68CA87D652C82CF849E), Fowler's [*Domain Specific Languages*](https://www.martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html), Pitrat's [*Artificial Beings, the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015), Parr's [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/), and the [Garbage Collection handbook](https://gchandbook.org/).

Once you have read several books, consider using parser generating tools like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/). Look also, for inspiration, inside the source code of open source software like [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), [fish](https://fishshell.com/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static analyzer, the [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) static analyzer.

Consider also reading proceedings of [ACM SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/) conferences.

> Use a recursive function that interprets the tree

Sometimes, that function could be [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (and a good optimizing C++ compiler like some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) could compile that to a tail call). Another approach is to specify -in written English at least- some [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) (like the [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) interpreter does), and translate your language into that bytecode, and write your bytecode interpreter.

Once you have some buggy interpreter, writing test cases for it is a matter of work. Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).